# Translating Python/JS to Java - JSON & HMAC

Tags: java, python, json, hmac, sha512

I am trying to translate the following Python example into Java code, but was getting an error around the format of the HTTP post and/or the HMAC signature I have created. If anyone could point at which part I could have possibly done wrong, it would be super helpful. Thank you!

Original Python example:

```
    PAYLOAD = {
      "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
      "price": 500000,
      "qty": 0.1,
      "currency", "btc"
    }

    def get_encoded_payload(payload):
      payload[u'nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)

      dumped_json = json.dumps(payload)
      encoded_json = base64.b64encode(dumped_json)
      return encoded_json

    def get_signature(encoded_payload, secret_key):
      signature = hmac.new(str(secret_key).upper(), str(encoded_payload), hashlib.sha512);
      return signature.hexdigest()

    def get_response(url, payload):
      encoded_payload = get_encoded_payload(payload)
      headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-COINONE-PAYLOAD': encoded_payload,
        'X-COINONE-SIGNATURE': get_signature(encoded_payload, SECRET_KEY)
      }
      http = httplib2.Http()
      response, content = http.request(URL, 'POST', headers=headers, body=encoded_payload)
      return content

    def get_result():
      content = get_response(URL, PAYLOAD)
      content = json.loads(content)

      return content

    if __name__   == "__main__":
        print get_result()
```

Original JS example:

```
    var crypto = require('crypto');
var request = require('request');
var ACCESS_TOKEN = '';
var SECRET_KEY = '';
var url = 'https://api.coinone.co.kr/v2/order/limit_buy/';
  var payload = {
  "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
  "price": 500000,
  "qty": 0.1,
  "currency": "btc",
  "nonce": Date.now()
};

payload = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64');

var signature = crypto
  .createHmac("sha512", SECRET_KEY.toUpperCase())
  .update(payload)
  .digest('hex');

var headers = {
  'content-type':'application/json',
  'X-COINONE-PAYLOAD': payload,
  'X-COINONE-SIGNATURE': signature
};

var options = {
  url: url,
  headers: headers,
  body: payload
};

request.post(options,
  function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

My code in Java:

```
    long nonce = (new Date()).getTime();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("currency", "BTC");
    json.put("price", 3000000);
    json.put("qty", 0.01);
    json.put("access_token", publicKey);
    json.put("nonce", nonce);

    System.out.println(json.toString());

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Entity<String> payload = Entity.json(json.toString());
    String message = json.toString(); 
    Response response = client.target(baseAddress+apiAddress)
      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
      .header("content-type", "application/json")
      .header("accept", "application/json")
      .header("X-COINONE-PAYLOAD", payload)
      .header("X-COINONE-SIGNATURE", CreateToken(message, privateKey.toUpperCase()))
      .post(payload);

    String body = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(body);

    ///////////
    private static String CreateToken(String message, String secretKey)
{
    String hash = "";
    try {    

        Mac sha512_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA512");
        sha512_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha512_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    System.out.println(hash);
    return hash;
}
```

It returns the following message:
{"errorCode":"130","errorMessage":"V2 API Nonce value must be a positive integer","result":"error"}

But this message seems to be a generic one - when input other nonce values, it also returns the same message

Comment: Show the error you are getting.

Comment: Don't describe the message.  SHOW THE EXACT TEXT of whatever message leads you to believe that it is not working!.  Even if you don't think it will help, remember than you don't know how to solve the problem, so you may not be the best judge of what information will be helpful.

Comment: Your JS code isn't even JS. It is python

Comment: Try reversing the order of your parameters (for your request), the first one should be the http request method, then the url.

Comment: sry attached a python code instead of js initially. JS is updated in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `message(payload)` and `hash(signature)` are wrong...

Example:

```
String payload = Base64.encodeBase64String(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String signature = CreateToken(payload, key.toUpperCase());

---------
private static String CreateToken(String message, String secretKey){
String hash = "";
try {    

    Mac sha512_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA512");
    sha512_HMAC.init(secret_key);

// hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha512_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
hash = Hex.encodeHexString(sha512_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));

}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error");
}
System.out.println(hash);
return hash;
```

}